# i can't get the right output in java

Tags: java

I have a problem with my program and I don't know why the names and the IDs of the objects don't show up right in the output and also the balance is not used in `chkBalance()` method Why ??I think the problem with the constructor but? ... and the output I get from this code is ...:

```
Customer Name   Customer ID  Balance
null            0.0          200
null            0.0          200
null            0.0          200
```

---

```
public class BankAccount {
    private int Balance;
    public String AccHolder_Name;
    public double AccHolder_ID;

    public BankAccount(String Name ,double ID,int Balance) {    
        Name = AccHolder_Name;
        ID = AccHolder_ID;
    }

    public void withDraw(int a) {
        Balance=a-Balance;
    }

    public void deposit(int b) {
        Balance=b+Balance;
    }

    public int chkBalance(){
        deposit(500);
        withDraw(700);

        return Balance;
    }

    public void Display () {
       System.out.println(AccHolder_Name+"\t\t"+AccHolder_ID+"\t\t"+Balance);
    }

    public static void main (String args []) {
        BankAccount o1=new BankAccount("Aos" , 1101558733 ,3000);
        BankAccount o2=new BankAccount("Ahmed" , 1101978733,5000);
        BankAccount o3=new BankAccount("Ali",1111650924,7000);

        System.out.println("Customer Name\tCustomer ID\tBalance");
        o1.chkBalance();
        o2.chkBalance();
        o3.chkBalance();
        o1.Display();
        o2.Display();
        o3.Display();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not clear, can you see how to write a [mcve] ? What is the input/output expected ? Also, you should know that a variable start with a lowercase and a class with an uppercase, this is hard to read like this..

Comment: Please explain the question thoroughly.

Comment: Also, be aware of [Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: Your constructor is ignoring all of the parameters sent to it.  And your `withdraw` logic is backwards.

Comment: I'm sorry i just signed up so i don't know much about the website  . i did what you told me and now the code is complete ... thank you so much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignments in the constructor is the wrong way arround. Also, you forgot to assign the Balance argument, which causes Balance to default to `0` and results in `200` after the calculations.

```
public BankAccount(String Name, double ID, int Balance) {
     this.AccHolder_Name = Name;
     this.AccHolder_ID = ID;
     this.Balance = Balance;
}
```

An important note on your [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): variables in Java use [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). It is also discouraged to abbreviate variable names unless they are considered an abbreviation standard. The resulting code would then be:

```
public BankAccount(String name, double id, int balance) {
     this.accountHolderName = name;
     this.accountHolderId = id;
     this.balance = balance;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your constructor you are assigning `null` to the given parameters and never assign `Balance`

```
public BankAccount(String Name ,double ID,int Balance) {
    Name = AccHolder_Name; // Will assign @AccHolder_Name to @Name
    ID = AccHolder_ID;
}
```

So you should reverse this assignment and set the `Balance` field with the given parameter :

```
public BankAccount(String Name ,double ID,int Balance) {
    AccHolder_Name = Name; // Will assign @Name to @AccHolder_Name
    AccHolder_ID = ID;
    this.Balance = Balance;
}
```

And about your variables names you should take a look to the [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).
The variables should use camel case and for good practice be well representative of their function.

So  `AccHolder_Name` should be `accHolderName` for example.

Comment: i would up vote if you told the question asker about the java naming conventions for parameters

Comment: Ahaha I was looking for a link explaining this better

Comment: i'd recommend saying something and later on adding the link. otherwise you risk OP reading your solution, but missing the remark ;)

Comment: I prefer Oracle link ^^ 
Yea tried to be clear enough without being aggressive ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of the BankAccount is indeed wrong. Since what '=' operation does is to give the value of the right variable to the left variable, and your code is reversed.
Another problem is that you don't initialize your Balance in your constructor and the compiler will then simply initialize it to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor has issue. Copy bellow code and replace your constructor and check.

```
public BankAccount(String Name ,double ID,int Balance) {
    this.AccHolder_Name = Name;
    this.AccHolder_ID = ID;
    this.Balance = Balance;
}
```

My suggestion is to learn java more. Basic you can learn from [Java Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/).

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you are assigning it in the other way. Assign it as below

```
public BankAccount(String Name ,double ID,int Balance) {

   this.AccHolder_Name = Name;
   this.AccHolder_ID = ID;
   this.Balance = Balance;

    }
```

There is always the variable you want to set on the left side and the value for it on the rigt side. As you want to set the String AccHolder_Name to the Name you are giving in the constructor, you have to do it just the other way around.

Comment: Thank you i did it  and the names and IDs are in the output now :)

Comment: Can you please mark this as answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes:

- a. Your constructor is incorrect and not saving the provided
  variables.

  this.AccHolder_Name=Name ;
  this.AccHolder_ID=ID;
  this.Balance=Balance;
- b. Your withdraw method is incorrect. It should be (balance =
  balance-a)

Please see the correct code below.

```
public class BankAccount {
    private int Balance ;
    public String AccHolder_Name;
    public double AccHolder_ID;

    public BankAccount(String Name ,double ID,int Balance) {

    this.AccHolder_Name=Name ;
    this.AccHolder_ID=ID;
    this.Balance=Balance;


    }
    public void withDraw(int a) {

        Balance=Balance-a;

    }

    public void deposit(int b) {

        Balance=b+Balance;

    }

    public int chkBalance(){
        deposit(500);
        withDraw(700);

        return Balance;
    }
    public void Display () {

        System.out.println(AccHolder_Name+"\t\t"+AccHolder_ID+"\t\t"+Balance);
    }

    public static void main (String args []) {
    BankAccount o1=new BankAccount("Aos" , 1101558733 ,3000);
    BankAccount o2=new BankAccount("Ahmed" , 1101978733,5000);
    BankAccount o3=new BankAccount("Ali",1111650924,7000);

    System.out.println("Customer Name\tCustomer ID\tBalance");
    o1.chkBalance();
    o2.chkBalance();
    o3.chkBalance();
    o1.Display();
    o2.Display();
    o3.Display();

    }
    }
```